# PHP does not fetch jquery generated input text fields

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have below form written in HTML / CSS

```
<div class="row" id="more-item">
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Description</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="item-desc" name="item-desc[]" placeholder="Enter the item description..">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Quantitiy</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="item-qty" name="item-qty[]"placeholder="How Many Items" data-validate="number">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputFile">CBM</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="item-cbm" name="item-cbm[]" placeholder="Enter item CBM" data-validate="number">

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputFile">Weight (Kg)</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="item-weight" name="item-weight[]" placeholder="Enter Weight in Kgs"  data-validate="number">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="res">
</div>
<div id="more-rows" style="padding-bottom:5px;">

    <input type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs" id="add-more-item" name="add-more-item" value="Add More">
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs" id="remove-more-item" name="remove-more-item" value="Add More">

</div>
```

Whenever user clicks on 'add-more-item' button, it keeps adding set of div rows same as above using below jquery.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var div_row = "<div class=\"row\" id=\"more-item\">";
    div_row += "<div class=\"col-md-2\">";
    div_row += "<div class=\"form-group\">";
    div_row += "<label for=\"exampleInputEmail1\">Description</label>";
    div_row += "<input type=\"text\" class=\"form-control\" id=\"item-desc\" name=\"item-desc[]\" placeholder=\"Enter the item description..\">";
    div_row += "</div>";
    div_row += "</div>";
    div_row += "<div class=\"col-md-2\">";
    div_row += "<div class=\"form-group\">";
    div_row += "<label for=\"exampleInputPassword1\">Quantitiy</label>";
    div_row += "<input type=\"text\" class=\"form-control\" id=\"item-qty\" name=\"item-qty[]\" placeholder=\"How Many Items\" data-validate=\"number\">";
    div_row += "</div>";
    div_row += "</div>";
    div_row += "<div class=\"col-md-2\">";
    div_row += "<div class=\"form-group\">";
    div_row += "<label for=\"exampleInputFile\">CBM</label>";
    div_row += "<input type=\"text\" class=\"form-control\" id=\"item-cbm\" name=\"item-cbm[]\" placeholder=\"Enter item CBM\" data-validate=\"number\">";
    div_row += "</div>";
    div_row += "</div>";
    div_row += "<div class=\"col-md-2\">";
    div_row += "<div class=\"form-group\">";
    div_row += "<label for=\"exampleInputFile\">Weight (Kg)</label>";
    div_row += "<input type=\"text\" class=\"form-control\" id=\"item-weight\" name=\"item-weight[]\" placeholder=\"Enter Weight in Kgs\"  data-validate=\"number\">";
    div_row += "</div>";
    div_row += "</div>";
    div_row += "</div>";

    $("#remove-more-item").click(function() {
        $('#res:last').remove();
    });
    $("#add-more-item").click(function() {
        $("#res").append(div_row);
    });
});
```

I don't have any issue with generating new rows when clicks on the button. My problem is PHP script does not fetch the data from the jquery generated fields but it does fetch from the static input.

Here is my php script:-

```
//cargo info
//$item_HBL = array();
$item_desc = array();
$item_qty = array();
$item_cbm = array();
$item_weight = array();


$item_HBL= $_POST['item-HBL'];
$item_desc = $_POST['item-desc'];
$item_qty   = $_POST['item-qty'];
$item_cbm   = $_POST['item-cbm'];
$item_weight = $_POST['item-weight'];
$port = $_POST['port'];
```

here is the result of print_r($_post)

```
Array ( [senderName] => [senderAddress] => [senderID] => [senderPhone] => [senderEmail] => [consigneeName] => [consigneeAddress] => [consigneeID] => [consigneePhone] => [consigneeEmail] => [item-HBL] => 1123 [item-desc] => Array ( [0] => Package One ) [item-qty] => Array ( [0] => 2 ) [item-cbm] => Array ( [0] => 1.200 ) [item-weight] => Array ( [0] => 3 ) [port] => Wattala )
```

Pls advice me on how to fix this issue. Thanks.

Comment: are the dynamically generated additional rows still inside the form tags? you should check that

Comment: @Ghost Yes. Here is the following up code. Sorry forgot to add that. `   <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Add Entry">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            </form>`

Comment: by they way, just a tip, instead of using an empty index array name on the name attributes, use a grouping instead, `[1][item-desc]`, `[1][item-qty]`, so that you'll get each batches per row, much easier to handle because they are in row groups, then increment it upon triggering additional rows

Comment: @Ghost Thanks for the tip. I was wondering how could i do that. Thanks a ton. But does not solve the issue i have. :(

Comment: looking at your current code, i'd only think thats the reason, your new rows appended on each click is not inside the `<form>` tags, anyway, just create an initialization variable `var row = 1;`, and then concatenate it inside the div rows, every additional row, just increment it `row++`

Comment: @Ghost I just noticed that after click on add rows it does not generate html code. How is it possible? Even though appended row appears. Pls have a look at my page source after clicking on add rows:- http://pastebin.com/MVxFmsu5

Comment: if you click on view source, it only shows original source code, not generated by javascript. Try inspect element in the browser instead.

Comment: @amitbakle Thank You. Pls help me with the above issue.

Comment: I tried out your code, its working. e.g. output Array ( [item-desc] => Array ( [0] => a [1] => d ) [item-qty] => Array ( [0] => c [1] => e ) [item-cbm] => Array ( [0] => b [1] => f ) [item-weight] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 ) )

Comment: @Ghost I'm totally blank in what u said. Pls elaborate. Thanks.

Comment: @amitbakle I guess you have mistaken. It works only for the first non-jquery generated input which is static. It does not fetch the data that comes from jquery generated inputs.

Comment: added 3 rows using 'Add More' and here is the output of print_r($_POST):  Array ( [item-desc] => Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => [3] => ) [item-qty] => Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => [3] => ) [item-cbm] => Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => [3] => ) [item-weight] => Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => [3] => ) ) . All i can say is your tags are misplaces. Try using 'Inspect Element' feature of browser such as Firefox/chrome and check if the new inputs are inside form tag.